# Express Handlebars-Page is routing to 404

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm creating a page using node which has the express and express-handlebars packages installed. I'm trying to create a menu across all of my pages through which I can jump to pages by clicking a button. My first 2 hyperlinks worked fine, then when I decided to add an aboutMe page and a testing page, they both redirect to 404.
File Structure

static.js

```
 |
Views

  ---home.handlebars
  ---404.handlebars
  ---other-page.handlebars
  ---aboutMe.handlebars
  ---testing.handelbars
     Layouts
     |
      main.handlebars
```

Code on my static.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var handlebars =require('express-      handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', 3000);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
      res.render('home');
}

app.get('/other-page', function(req,res){
    res.render('other-page');
});

app.get('/aboutMe', function(req,res){
    res.render('aboutMe');
});

app.get('/testing', function(req,res){
    res.render('testing');
});

app.use(function(req,res){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});

app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.type('plain/text');
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') +'; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

A snippet from my main.handlebars where im linking:
    Home
    Other-Page
    About
    Testing

Comment: A snippet from my main.handlebars where im linking:
    <a href="http://**.**.***.***:3000" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Home</a>
    <a href="http://**.**.***.***:3000/other-page" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Other-Page</a>
    <a href="http://**.**.***.***:3000/aboutMe" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">About</a>
    <a href="http://**.**.***.***:3000/testing" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Testing</a>

Comment: If you want to add more code to your question, please use the 'edit' link instead of commenting it. What you've commented is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

We'll,after hours of headbanging i've solved my problem. I realize that I had node forever running on static.js, i made changes to the file, and those didn't take place until i stopped and restarted node on static.js. :)